# Collapse or hide CSS dropdown menu when a menu item is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a CSS dropdown menu that seems to be working fine except one thing, which is to collapse the dropdown menu items every time any of the links inside submenu is clicked. So when a user click a link in the in the submenu they are able to view the content in a  that I have in the same the page using JQuery.

I have seen different questions regarding how to collapse dropdown menus onClick but they do not appear to help in my case.

Here is my sample html and CSS, I hope someone can help me correct this issue.
Initially I had to struggle to load the content into the

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>

                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css_dropdown.css" />
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
                <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
                <title>CSS Dropdown menu with load content in DIV element</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <ul class="sectiontitle">
                        <li>Documents <ul class="section">
                                        <li><a href="./docs/test1.html">Document 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="./docs/test2.html">Document 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="./docs/test3.html">Document 3</a></li>
                                </ul></li>
                        <li>Items <ul class="section">
                                        <li><a href="./items/test1.html">Item 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="./items/test2.html">Item 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="./items/test3.html">Item 3</a></li>
                                </ul></li>
                        <li>Products <ul class="section">
                                        <li><a href="./prods/test1.html">Product 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="./prods/test2.html">Product 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="./prods/test3.html">Product 3</a></li>
                                </ul></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="container">
                        <!-- This is an empty container for loading linked content allowing to stay on the same page as the dropdown list -->
                </div>
                <!--This script needs to be loaded last for the browser to accept to make it work.-->
                <script type="text/javascript">

$(".section").on("click", "a", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".container").load( $(this).prop("href") );

      // Stop regular handling of "click" in IE (and some others)
    return false;
}); 
</script>
        </body>
</html>
```

and here is the CSS

```css
    body, .title.topictitle2 {
    width:auto;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-left:.8em;
    font-family:"news cycle", helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: .95em;
    height:auto;

 }
#container {

    position:fixed;
    top:2.25em;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    background: #c65;
    width: 100%;
    /*overflow:inherit;*/
    z-index: 1;
}

.sectiontitle{

    margin:0;
    padding:0 1em;
    background:#194879;
    height:2.25em;
    list-style:none;

    z-index: 2;

  /*  position:fixed;*/
}

.sectiontitle > li{ /* We target only the list element inside ul.sectiontitle class*/

    float:left;
    height:100%;
    margin-right:0; /*To control how far apart from the right each <li> should be positioned from the other*/
    padding:0 .02em;
}

.sectiontitle > li{

    float:left;
    height:100%;
    color:white;
    font-family:"news cycle", helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:.9em;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height:2;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    /* border-right: solid white .03em;*/
}

ul.sectiontitle li:hover{
    color:orange;
    border-bottom:.1em dotted #224480;
    /*  text-decoration:underline; */
}

/* Contextual positioning for the children under the .sectiontitle list items*/

ul.section{

    position:relative;
    left:-1.12em;

    z-index: 3;
}

ul.section{

    /*  width:10em;*/
    margin:0 0 0;
    padding:0 0 0;
    list-style:none;
    background:repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(15, 161, 224);
    position:relative; /*Very important to keep the children ul.section aligned with its parent ul.sectiontitle*/
    top:-1000em;

}

ul.section{
    width:auto; /* dropdown list width better when set to auto*/
    margin:0 auto 0.3em auto;
    white-space:inherit;
    border: solid #224480 0.01em;
}

ul.section li a{

    height:100%;
    display:block;
    padding:0.3em 1em 0;  /*Set padding around the text in the list items under ul.section elements*/
    color:#fff;
    /*font-weight:bold;*/
    text-decoration:none;

    }

ul.section li a:hover{
    background:#69F;
    /*text-decoration:underline;*/
}

/* This controls the position of the child ul.section from the top horizontal bar*/
.sectiontitle > li:hover ul.section{
    top:.47em;
}

.container p:last-child:focus {
    background: #399;
}
```

Comment: If I understand you want to show the sub li tags when you click the principal li tag?

Comment: Actually the submenu shows and the links work fine, but what I need is to be able to hide/collapse the submenu or dropdown list items when one of the list items, which are also holding links is clicked. So how do you achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the menu when the mouse leaves by using the `.mouseleave` method.

If you want to hide the menu when an item is clicked, you can add this to your code, in the `<head>` tag preferably. The following code is in jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        $("#menu").hide();    //or $("#menu").slideUp() if you want it to slide up instead of just disappearing.
    });
});
```

This tells the browser to close menu whenever a link is clicked. If you have other links in your web-page text, the you could include the menu links in a class, and use the class instead.

For example:

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li><a href="#" class="mitem">Item 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

And then the jQuery code would be:

```
$(function(){
    $(".mitem").click(function(){
        $("#menu").hide();
    });
});
```

Here is a full working example - [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zKF5m/2/)

Hope that helped `:)`

Comment: No problems `:)` Glad I helped.

Comment: But for pure css menus, it doesn't unhide on hover, right?